# Sum if 2 columns met the values of another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here are my values:
C1 is set by other values
C14:C214 is set by a drop down box
A14:A214 is a typed in Date
If both Critera are met I want to sum H14:H214

```
=SUM(IF((TimeLog!C14:C214="*Vitamin Shoppe#*")+(TimeLog!A14:A214=C1),TimeLog!H14:H214))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `SUMIFS` appear to be an appropriate formula to me. Can you try it? The documentation for the formula should be enough, and there are quite a few guides/tutorials on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Very good advice, I check ed "hints" as you type the code in and matched it and it worked! `=SUMIFS(TimeLog!H14:H214, TimeLog!C14:C214, "*Vitamin Shoppe#*", TimeLog!A14:A214,C1)`